# Greedy Regex Matching

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match a string that looks something like this:

```
<$Fexample text in here>>
```

with this expression:

```
<\$F(.+?)>{2}
```

However, there are some cases where my backreferenced content includes a ">", thus something like this:

```
<$Fexample text in here <em>>>
```

only matches `example text in here <em` in the backreference. What do I need to do to conditionally return a correct backrefernce with or without these html entities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add start and end anchors to the regex as:

```
^<\$F(.+?)>{2}$
```

Comment: I don't know if you can assume this from the question, else dropping the ? would suffice

Comment: I forgot to mention the absence of anchors is intentional. The string may appear anywhere within the line.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<\$F(.+?)>>(?!>)
```

The `(?!>)` forces only the last `>>` in a long sequence of `>>>..>>>` will be matched.

---

Edit:

```
<\$F(.+?>*)>>
```

Also works.

Comment: In case you are wondering, that's negative lookahead. See: [Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: +1: But I think <\$F(.+?)>>+ would be more performant as there's no backtracking.

Comment: @Curtain: But then the extra `>` won't be in the capture group.

Answer (score 0):

Please note than tu **truly** do what (I think) you want to do, you would have to interpret well-formed bracket expressions, which is not possible in a regular language.

In other words, `<$Fexample <tag <tag <tag>>> example>> oh this should not happen>` will return `example <tag <tag <tag>>> example>> oh this should not happen` as the capture group.